# How to match data in different columns in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset simplified as below: there are multiple customers and each CUSTOMER may have several loans. A `CUSTOMER` with at least 1 `LOAN_DEFAULT` is marked as `CUSTOMER_DEFAULT`, and the `DEFAULT_DATE` is the first time of default.

```
CUSTOMER LOAN   DATE    AMOUNT LOAN_DEFAULT CUSTOMER_DEFAULT DEFAULT_DATE CLASSIFICATION
1        101   201601    100    Y               Y            201501          S
1        102   201603    100    N               Y            201501          S
1        103   201501    100    Y               Y            201501          S
1        104   201501    200    N               Y            201501          S
2        201   201601    100    N               N               -            M
2        202   201603    100    N               N               -            M
```

1. How can I calculate the loan amount for a customer at the first default date, e.g. 201501 for customer 1 that equals to the total `AMOUNT` at that month, that I should get a number of 300? 
   What I think of is compare the `DATE` and `DEFAULT_DATE` and if they are the same, use sum function. But my code didn't work.
2. I want to summarise the number of default customers by Classification, but by using summarise function it seems not working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can sum `AMOUNT` value where `DATE` is equal to `first` `DEFAULT_DATE` for each `CUSTOMER`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(CUSTOMER) %>% 
  summarise(total_sum  = sum(AMOUNT[DATE == first(DEFAULT_DATE)]))

#   CUSTOMER total_sum
#     <int>     <int>
#1        1       300
#2        2         0
```

To get number of default customers for each `CLASSIFICATION` we can do :

```
df %>%
  group_by(CLASSIFICATION) %>%
  summarise(no_default_cust = n_distinct(CUSTOMER[CUSTOMER_DEFAULT == "Y"]))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CUSTOMER = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), LOAN = c(101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 201L, 202L), DATE = c(201601L, 201603L, 201501L, 
201501L, 201601L, 201603L), AMOUNT = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 100L), LOAN_DEFAULT = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), CUSTOMER_DEFAULT = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
DEFAULT_DATE = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-", 
"201501"), class = "factor"), CLASSIFICATION = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("M", "S"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of `AMOUNT` per `CUSTOMER`. With `x[x$DATE == x$DEFAULT_DATE,]` you can subset to those lines where `DATE` equals to `DEFAULT_DATE`.

```
aggregate(AMOUNT ~ CUSTOMER, x[x$DATE == x$DEFAULT_DATE,], sum)
#  CUSTOMER AMOUNT
#1        1    300
```

To get the number of default customers by Classification you can use `table` in combination with `unique`:

```
table(unique(x[x$CUSTOMER_DEFAULT=="Y",c("CUSTOMER", "CLASSIFICATION")])[,2])
#M S 
#0 1
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="CUSTOMER LOAN   DATE    AMOUNT LOAN_DEFAULT CUSTOMER_DEFAULT DEFAULT_DATE CLASSIFICATION
1        101   201601    100    Y               Y            201501          S
1        102   201603    100    N               Y            201501          S
1        103   201501    100    Y               Y            201501          S
1        104   201501    200    N               Y            201501          S
2        201   201601    100    N               N               -            M
2        202   201603    100    N               N               -            M")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(total_sum  = sum(AMOUNT[DATE == first(DEFAULT_DATE)])), CUSTOMER]
```